# How to run xfce4 on debian on VNC startup?

Tags: xfce

I have a debian server. It is running the latest stable version of Debian.

The following commands have been entered:

```
apt-get install xfce4 xfce4-goodies
```

I have also added `startxfce4` to the VNC startup file.

However, I get this black and white dotted screen when I start vnc:

[image: xfce4]

**Is there a way to make the xfce4 desktop run properly?**

(it's a server, so i dont have the monitor, physical access etc)

Answer (score 4):

```bash
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
startxfce4 &

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &

#it works for me
```

Comment: Maybe explain what the OP did/is doing wrong so that he understands why this works.

Comment: This works for me too, but I don't know why. Could you please explain each line?

Comment: Seems to be related to this bug: https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=7502 I'm betting there's a reference to the window manager already running in the log files for the VNC server startup with other scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Use `xfce4-session` instead of `startxfce4`, it's in the package `xfce4-session`.

Answer (score -1):

```
vi /root/.vnc/xstartup


#!/bin/sh
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
startxfce4 &

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
```

Comment: Add an explanation to your answer, please.